# Sort struct by int value

Tags: c, struct

I got an assignment to make program that asks for a number of teams, their names, wins and losses. I have got two problems with the code.

- How do I get the team names with spaces in them correctly?
- And how to sort the teams by total value (total=wins-losses) before printing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 25

typedef struct {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int wins;
    int losses;
    int total;
} Total;

Total readTeamInfo(void);
void printInfo(Total tt, int);

int main(void) {

    int i, teams;

    printf("Number of teams > ");
    scanf("%d", &teams);

    Total data[teams];

    for (i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
        data[i] = readTeamInfo();
        data[i].total = data[i].wins - data[i].losses;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
        printInfo(data[i], i);
    }
    return (0);
}

Total readTeamInfo(void) {

    Total tt;

    printf("Team name > ");
    scanf("%s", tt.name);

    printf("Wins > ");
    scanf("%d", &tt.wins);

    printf("Losses > ");
    scanf("%d", &tt.losses);

    return (tt);
}

void printInfo(Total tt, int i) {
    printf("Team #%d %s: %d wins and %d loses\n", i + 1, tt.name, tt.wins, tt.losses);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` if the value can have spaces. Use `fgets()` to read a whole line, then [remove the newline at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

Comment: Don't use `scanf`.  If you do use `scanf`, you can't use `%s` if you expect to distinguish whitespace. You should *never* use `%s` but should always use a width modifier and write it `%24s` (you can dynamically generate the 24 from the macro if you need to). You *must* *always* *check* the value returned by scanf.  But it's really easier if you just stop using `scanf`.

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Use the `qsort()` function to sort the array.

Comment: And for qsort use a comparator similar to the following int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) { return ((Total *)a)->total - ((Total *)b)->total; }

Answer (score 0):

To read the team name, you can use `scanf()` with a `" %24[^\n]"` format. This format specifies a class of characters, namely all characters different from `'\n'` and the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array before the null terminator. The number `24` is hardcoded here and there is no simple way to specify this number as an expression involving `NAME_LENGTH`. An alternative solution is to use `fgets()` to read a full line and strip the newline.

To sort the array of structures, you should use `qsort()` with a custom comparison function.

Also check the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input and exit with an error message.

It is quite confusing to name the team structure `Total`. You should use meaningful names such as `Team`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 25

typedef struct {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int wins;
    int losses;
    int total;
} Team;

Team readTeamInfo(void);
void printInfo(Team tt, int);

int compare_teams(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const Team *t1 = p1;
    const Team *t2 = p2;
    return (t1->total > t2->total) - (t1->total < t2->total);
}

int main() {
    int i, teams;

    printf("Number of teams > ");
    if (scanf("%d", &teams) != 1 || teams <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Team data[teams];

    for (i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
        data[i] = readTeamInfo();
        data[i].total = data[i].wins - data[i].losses;
    }

    qsort(data, teams, sizeof(*data), compare_teams);

    for (i = 0; i < teams; i++) {
        printInfo(data[i], i);
    }
    return 0;
}

Team readTeamInfo(void) {
    Team tt;

    printf("Team name > ");
    if (scanf(" %24[^\n]", tt.name) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Wins > ");
    if (scanf("%d", &tt.wins) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Losses > ");
    if (scanf("%d", &tt.losses) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return tt;
}

void printInfo(Team tt, int i) {
    printf("Team #%d %s: %d wins and %d loses\n",
           i + 1, tt.name, tt.wins, tt.losses);
}
```